# Lost data because of 301 error (POST)

Tags: php, html, post

I've a 301 error after doing my POST Form...
When I submit my form, I lose all my data and I don't know why.
I search on the net but I don't understand anything because my english is too bad to do it...

My HTML code addSwitchPort.html :

```
<form action="addSwitchPort.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Switch</td> 
        <td><input type="text" class='switchName' name="switchName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="buttonIndex" type="submit" name='vlan' value="Add & vlan" style="width:200px"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

My PHP code addSwitchPort.php :

```
<?php
$switchName = $_POST['switchName'];

echo $switchName;
echo '???';

$bra = addSwitchPort($switchName);
```

This is the code of `addSwitchPort` but there is no bug on this function because `$switchName` is empty

```
function addSwitchPort($switchName)
{
    global $conn;
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $switchID = getIDSwitch($switchName);
        try {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO switchport (switchID) VALUES 
            ("'.$switchID.'"")';
            $conn->exec($sql);
            echo 'SUCCESS';
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }   

}
```

Do you know why the `echo` is empty ? There is no way because this is the right location !

Comment: you tagged this as ajax, why? Plus, if that's your actual code, you've a missing `</form>` tag. and what does `addSwitchPort()` do? show full code please

Comment: voted to close as unclear

Comment: I added things that you asked, sorry for this... But the `</form>` is here, and there is no problem in `addSwitchPort()`

Comment: HTTP 301 is a redirect, you are losing your data because the browser is being forwarded to a new URL. Check your server config

Comment: besides an answer already given below, make sure that your file's case is indeed `addSwitchPort.php` and not `addswitchport.php` all in lowercase or other case. This is important when on Linux, if you are on that type of server. `addSwitchPort.php` and `addswitchport.php` are two different animals altogether (when on Linux).

Comment: also check if there's anything in `.htaccess` such as a mod rewrite

Comment: the thing is that my `addSwitchPort.php` is find because the echo is writing, and it's not about the .htaccess coz it works for others form

Comment: see the "answer" below then. I'm out of ideas. Edit: or use `isset()` or `!empty()` on your POST array.

Comment: All my POST values are empty... The post from my `HTML` is full but the post from my `PHP` is empty

Comment: I think I found your error, or part of it - this `("'.$switchID.'"")';` you've an extra quote in there. Try changing it to `("'.$switchID.'")';` or try changing your quotes and query to 
`$sql = "INSERT INTO switchport (switchID) VALUES 
            ('".$switchID."')";` and `$conn->exec($sql);` to `$conn->execute($sql);`

Comment: and replace `$switchName = $_POST['switchName'];` with `if(!empty($_POST['switchName'])){
  $switchName = $_POST['switchName'];
} else{ echo "Post is empty";}`

Comment: so, where are we at here? should I delete my comments if they're of no use and make way for fresh ones by others? it's filling up the comments area.

Comment: seems like I am blowing bubbles here. Well, I wish you best of luck.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't at work, that's why I didn't answer... The solution was to delete the file and to create another with the same name... I don't know why, but it worked...

Comment: If you are completely sure that the name of the field matched, then itI could have been a matter of permissions

Comment: yeah, maybe... was strange, but thanks anyway for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for
>   permanent URL redirection, meaning current links or records using the
>   URL that the response is received for should be updated. The new URL
>   should be provided in the Location field included with the response.

So, in your form declaration:

```
<form action="addSwitchPort.php" method="post">
```

Make you sure that `addSwitchPort.php` is in the same dir that `addSwitchPort.html`.

Comment: The path is correct because the echo is writing on `addSwitchPort.php`

Comment: Then, what did you say about a 301 redirect? "I've a 301 error after doing my POST Form."

Answer (score 0):

I was going nuts, trying to figure out why my fetch() call with json post data was working -- but not giving ANY data on the php side (and yes, I'd tried all of the proper variations for reading the incoming data!).

Turns out it was a missing slash on the fetch URL!

This caused the HTTP Status to show a 301 and no data to make it to my php code on the server. Super frustrating!!!

On the small chance it saves someone some ugly hours, make sure you try the 2nd:

1. `return fetch('/checkout/api/paypal/order/capture', {`
   (gave a 301 and zero POST data in php)
2. `return fetch('/checkout/api/paypal/order/capture/', {`
   (worked just fine!)